# Test type of exception encapsulated in Failure() with scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

Here is a toy example:

I have a method `last[T](ts: Seq[T]): Try[T]` which returns either:

- the last element of a non-empty list wrapped in a `Success`, or
- a `NoSuchElementException` wrapped in a `Failure`.

I have been reading the [scalatest doc pertaining to TryValues](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.TryValues) and came up with the following scalatest:

```
"The solution" should "Find the last element of a non-empty list" in {
      last(Seq(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)).success.value should equal (8)
      // ...
    }

  it should "Fail with NoSuchElementException on an empty list" in {
    // Option 1: what I would like to do but is not working
    last(Nil).failure.exception should be a[NoSuchElementException]

    // Option 2: is working but actually throws the Exception, and does not test explicitly test if was in a Failure
    a [NoSuchElementException] should be thrownBy {last(Nil).get}
}
```

Is there a way to make my option 1 work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `shouldBe` word to assert type, like:

```
test.failure.exception shouldBe a [NoSuchElementException]
```

for type not equal, like:

```
test.failure.exception should not be an [NoSuchElementException]
```

See more:
http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers

Comment: Really inconsistent syntax... Thanks!